# ImportError: No module named pandas in Zeppelin (EMR)

Tags: pandas, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have an EMR cluster with Spark/Hive/Zeppelin. In my Zeppelin notebook, I tried to import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

But I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

How can I resolve this issue? Is this because pandas not installed in the EMR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a matter of installing pandas in the master node:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```